# Create gaps in shapes created with loop AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

A stupid question possibly that shouldn't be asked here, but I can't find anything to help me, so anyway, I've created a quick collision system and I made it so you can collide with multiple shapes using 1 bunch of if statements by using arrays. Now rather than defining each wall and creating them, I'm trying to use a loop. It creates them but I can't tell if it's created only 1 or more, so I tried making a gap in-between each wall, but it seems to just move all of them (assuming it made more than one).

Code:

```
    for (var i:int = 1; i < 3; i++)
    {
        var MyWall = new Sprite();
        MyWall.graphics.beginFill(0xAABBCC)
        MyWall.graphics.drawRect(100*i+201, 30, 200, 125)
        MyWall.graphics.endFill();
        WallsList.push(MyWall)
        addChild(MyWall)
    }
```

Comment: What happens if you draw the rect at 0 and then set the x coordinate on your new Sprite to 100*I + 201?

Comment: Like this? MyWall.x = 100*i + 201 after drawing it and adding the child

Comment: And how does that look, visually?

Comment: I might try something like drawing each one a different color or iterating through WallsList to see if the x coordinate is where I thought I put each one as debug steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has one simple problem: the rectangles that you are drawing overlap with each other.

Rect 1 is at 301x30, and it's 200x125 (i.e. ends at x=501).
Rect 2 is at 401x30, and it's 200x125 (i.e. ends at x=601).

You'll see this immediately if you change colors:

```
var colours = [0xAABBCC, 0xFF0000];
for (var i:int = 1; i < 3; i++)
{
    var MyWall = new Sprite();
    MyWall.graphics.beginFill(colours[i-1])
    MyWall.graphics.drawRect(100*i+201, 30, 200, 125)
    MyWall.graphics.endFill();
    addChild(MyWall)
}
```

You can solve this by either making narrower walls:

```
var colours = [0xAABBCC, 0xFF0000];
for (var i:int = 1; i < 3; i++)
{
    var MyWall = new Sprite();
    MyWall.graphics.beginFill(colours[i-1])
    MyWall.graphics.drawRect(100*i+201, 30, 50, 125)
    MyWall.graphics.endFill();
    addChild(MyWall)
}
```

or by spacing them further apart:

```
var colours = [0xAABBCC, 0xFF0000];
for (var i:int = 1; i < 3; i++)
{
    var MyWall = new Sprite();
    MyWall.graphics.beginFill(colours[i-1])
    MyWall.graphics.drawRect(250*i, 30, 200, 125)
    MyWall.graphics.endFill();
    addChild(MyWall)
}
```

Edit:  As @BotMaster rightly pointed out, this solution won't handle collision detection properly.  Both your walls will be at x=0, y=0, height=155.  For the "spacing them further apart" code block, the first wall will have width=450, and the second one will have width=700 -- objects will detect collisions in what looks like empty space.

Comment: This is accepted as the right answer but is not really helping the PO. It provides a solution to his problem but doesn't fix the underlying true problem. PO wants a collision system but those walls have all the same x,y, matrix because of the way they are drawn. Guess he will have to come back for that but at the end your solution will have to be abandoned.

Comment: @BotMaster PO?  I'm not familiar with that term.  Re: collision detection, you're absolutely right. My answer only addresses the visuals, not collision detection.

Answer (score 1):

if you draw that way then all walls will have common coordinate and transform matrix but different look. Most of the time this is not needed and is only going to add to your confusion. Instead they need to be drawn the same way and then placed at the right place so same drawing:

```
var xpos:Number = 0;
var ypos:Number = 30;
for (var i:int = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    var wall:Sprite = new Sprite();
    wall.graphics.beginFill(0xAABBCC)
    wall.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 200, 125)
    wall.graphics.endFill();
    WallsList.push(wall)
    addChild(wall)
    wall.y = ypos;
    xpos += i * 100;
    wall.x = 201 + xpos;        
}
```

Comment: This is a better structure for a solution than my code, but it retains the math errors from the question.  The walls will be 200px wide, but they'll only be 100px apart.

Comment: That's correct I should have provided a complete solution. I was hoping Badfitz66 would see he could do the same but by using x,y which I'm sure he's more comfortable using and understanding.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is:

Instead of the code:

```
MyWall.graphics.drawRect(100*i+201, 30, 200, 125)
```

Try the next one:

```
MyWall.graphics.drawRect(100+201*i, 30, 200, 125)
```